# Unable to build ad-hoc distribution to iOS using Appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator

I cannot build my app for ad-hoc distribution, though it deploys and runs on an iphone when directly connected.

I am using Appcelerator v5.1.4.201909061933, SDK 8.0.1.GA, Xcode v9.2.

I have created, downloaded and installed an ad-hoc distribution profile.
I have two development certificates - one for development and the other for distribution. Could this be a problem?

Can somebody please explain the relationships between development certificates and distribution profiles as not all of my profiles show on the 'Run Configurations' page.
Looking forward to getting some help with this.

Brian

Comment: please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Update: I have removed the current Development Certificate and Provisioning Profiles, generated new ones, and it now works. Hurrah!